# Term or word for super-sensitive people

Tags: word-usage, usage

Word for people who always believe others are speaking negatively about them.

Comment: paranoid is a good word

Comment: The title conflicts with the description in the body. Someone super [sensitive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sensitive), or highly sensitive is someone who is extremely emotive and sensitive to criticism, (they take things too personally) and become distressed  when they witness any act of (perceived) cruelty.

Comment: "Hypersensitive".

Comment: This requires a diagnosis more than a single word.

Comment: "It's like I'm **paranoid** lookin' over my back. It's like a whirlwind inside of my head. It's like I can't stop what I'm hearing within..." :(

Answer (score 2):

Such a person could **have a thin skin**. (Unlike a thick skin as sung about by Sia in "Elastic Heart".)

> **[skin](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/skin?s=t) - Idioms**
>
> 31. **have a thin skin** - to be extremely sensitive to criticism or rebuffs; be easily offended

*Source: Dictionary.com*